# How to replace a token in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have a template with tokens which needs to be replaced with actual values and then sent via email. In order to do this I need help in replacing my tokens with some value and extracting type of token from token.

Token: `{{token_type:token_content}}`

eg: `{{input_box:greeting}}`

Code [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/qrrbwvmc/1/)

```
var str = "<p class=MsoNormal>{{input_box:greeting}},", regex = "/{{[a-z\:]+}}/"; 
var n = str.replace(regex, someValue);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  n;
```

Comment: Your not describing exactly how and what you want to send to your backend for the e-mail. Also you are not actually using AngularJS so it shouldn't be included as a tag.

Comment: @maythesource.com: I will send the template with replaced tokens with values to server side, which is `n` in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex should be delimited using forward slashes, not by quotes.
In the OP code,

```
regex = "/{{[a-z\:]+}}/";
```

is a **string**, not a regex.

Use a non-greedy regex to match any string that starts with `{{` until `}}`.

```
regex = /{{.*?}}/;
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/qrrbwvmc/4/) - [**RegEx101 Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uW1pI8/1)

```js
var myFunction = function() {
  var str = "<p class=MsoNormal>{{input_box:greeting}},",
    regex = /{{.*?}}/;
  console.log(str);
  console.log(regex);
  var n = str.replace(regex, "Hello There");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = n;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Replace</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```